# route by name in url with express and mongoose not id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hello i'm trying to route by name not id
my schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  author: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Campground', campgroundSchema);
```

the route is

```
 router.get('/:campground_id', function(req, res) {  
 Campground.findById(req.params.campground_id).populate('comments').exec(
     function(err, foundCampground) {
       if (err) {
        req.flash('error', 'Campground was not found');
         res.redirect('back');
       } else {
         res.render('campgrounds/show', {
          campground: foundCampground
         });
      }
     }   ); });
```

i tried to use

```
router.get('/:campground_id', function(req, res) {
Campground.find({name: req.params.name}).populate('comments').exec(
```

it does not seem to work any idea ?

Comment: can you console log `name`? is it catching something?

Comment: problem solved i used Campground.findOne({name: req.params.name}).populate('comments').exec(